# Facing issues in doing round off in Java

Tags: java

I have to show the fund value to customers for the next 30 years in one of my application , but the issue is there are some decimal values present , so we have to do the round off those values so that we will be calculated properly .e.g we there are values like, 414.598940334717 , it should round off to 414.60 but it is not getting round off with this function till 414.61 according to the spreadsheet.
I have written this method

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(Double.toString(414.598940334717));

bd = bd.setScale(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP );
```

Comment: when I tried your code, it run successfully and returns `414.60`..

Comment: But the Spreadsheet is giving 414.61

Comment: are you sure this is the code which inserts values in spreadsheet? What you want to do> will you elaborate your problem more briefly?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
  System.out.print(twoDForm.format(Double.valueOf("414.588940334717")));
```

Comment: however you can not roundup .59 to .61 , it will be .60

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your issue...

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(Double.toString(414.598940334717));    
bd = bd.setScale(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP );
System.out.println("" + bd);
```

**Output**

414.60

My usual trick to do round-ups like this is to just use casting:

```
double d = 414.598940334717;
double rounded = (int)(d * 100 + 0.5) / 100.0;
System.out.println("" + rounded);
```

**Output**

414.6